# Why is DotLocal redirection applied even if the exe has a manifest

Tags: windows, dll, manifest

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection), `.local` redirection is disabled when the application has a manifest. But I observed that even if the EXE file has an embedded manifest, if there's a folder `<exe name>.exe.local` in the application directory, the redirection is still applied.

For example, here is the embedded manifest for `foo.exe`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

If I place a folder `foo.exe.local` in the application directory, then Windows tries to load `comctl32.dll` from `foo.exe.local\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.437_none_05b63dca071e5dd6\comctl32.dll`, rather than the one under `C:\Windows\WinSxS`.

I tested this on Windows 10 x64 version 10.0.17763.437, and on Windows 7 x86 with latest patches.

So why is `.local` redirection still followed? How do I change the manifest to disable `.local` completely?

Comment: This seems unlikely to be the issue you're encountering since you probably didn't add this registry key, but there is a registry key that overrides your app manifest for .local DLL redirection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection?redirectedfrom=MSDN#optional-configure-the-registry-if-you-have-an-app-manifest

Answer (score 2):

I have observed the same behavior as well.  I would love to know if anyone knows how to disable Windows .local ("dotLocal") redirection - I believe this is a side effect of WinSxS side-by-side loading.

I have tested on Windows 10 x64, version 10.0.17763.503.

Note that I have discovered I can use an undocumented "**loadFrom**" feature of the manifest to force COMCTL32.DLL to load from the \Windows\System32 directory.  However, this only works if the executable does not require Visual Styles and can use COMCTL32 version 5.x.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
   <security>
     <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
     </requestedPrivileges>
   </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <file name="comctl32.dll" loadFrom="%SystemRoot%\System32\" />
</assembly>
```